# .NET Framework 4.5 - EF exclude "ufloat" columns from MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to write program to help myself manage some data on server by remote accessing it through SSH Tunnel.

Server MySQL version: 5.1.73-cll

I'm on PC with Visual Studio 2012, .NET Framework 4.5, newest MySQL Connector (6.9.4) and MySQL for VS (1.2.3) installed. Connection to database works fine, I created .edmx file with "Generate from database" wizard. I made some associations and started building my programm. But then I realized that some columns are gone. Tried to Update model from database and then saw Messages (not Errors) in error log:

```
Message 30  The data type 'ufloat' is currently not supported for the target .NET Framework version; the column 'spa' in table 'game_data.monster_sold' was excluded.
```

And message like this for every ufloat and udouble. I tried to look for solution but looks like there is no match for this message. Haven't found even a single topic about it but maybe I just don't know where to look (or made some newbie mistakes).
I'm kinda new to work with MySQL Connector and EF.

So here is my question - has anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it (on either side, client or server)?

I can paste content of EF files if it will be necessery. Thanks for any responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF supports specific data types only. The message is a warning to you that it will be unable to map those unsupported columns to your objects.

If you can't change your column's underlying data type, consider creating a View that is simply a facade to the physical Table but type casts the unsupported columns to a more common data type that is supported by EF. Then simply configure EF to map/read to/from the View instead of the Table. Should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to change datatype in database. To be sure: signed float will be supportef by EF? I need to wait for nighttime to change it in database though, to avoid errors.

Comment: Signed floats should be supported. When in doubt, consult the documentation or do a quick unit test.

Comment: Thanks! Changing it worked just fine. And I know, but I'm just starting with C#, .NET, MySQL, EF... and had no idea where exactly to look.

Anyway, thanks for help.